# How to call a function with multiple nested mysql queries multiple times inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function called foo that uses the mysql module: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

```
fooz = [{query1:'',query2:'',query3:''},{query1:'',query2:'',query3:''},{query1:'',query2:'',query3:''},{query1:'',query2:'',query3:''}]


function foo (query1,query2,query3){ 
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig);
connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
   connection.query(query2, function (error, results, fields) {
      connection.query(query3, function (error, results, fields) {
      connection.end()


    })
  })
})
```

I then have a for loop that will call this function more then once.

```
    for (i=0;i<fooz.length;i++){foo(fooz[i].query1,fooz[i].query2,fooz[i].query3)}
```

What happens is that foo is called multiple times but only executes one of the functions and then just stops. What do I do to make sure that the foo function is executed more then once? Thank you!

Comment: Need to become comfortable with Promises or async/await to accomplish this. It depends on which things you want to wait for vs if you want to run queries simultaneously as well. As long as fooz.length is > 1, there's no reason that foo shouldn't be run more than once.

Comment: Foo is called multiple times but it is only being run once and then the entire program just stalls as if it is waiting for something.

Comment: Yes so what I would do is try converting things to Promises and then wait for the promises. I'll try to show in an answer soon

Comment: Do you really need to perform three separate queries, or can you let the database do the work that your JavaScript would have by writing a more specific query?

Comment: I have to do separate queries

Answer (score 0):

You could call your for loop recursively. Just be sure to have an exit condition

```
fooz = [{query1:'',query2:'',query3:''},{query1:'',query2:'',query3:''},{query1:'',query2:'',query3:''},{query1:'',query2:'',query3:''}];

foo(0);
function foo(index) {
    if (index >= fooz.length) {
        return;
    }
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig);
    connection.query(fooz[index].query1, function (error, results, fields) {
        connection.query(fooz[index].query2, function (error, results, fields) {
            connection.query(fooz[index].query3, function (error, results, fields) {
                connection.end();
                foo(index + 1);
            })
        })
    });
}
```

The good part about this is that your query list is also non blocking.
You also might want to consider opening your connection before calling foo and closing it when you are done iterating.

Comment: That is what I am doing.

Comment: Unless you forgot to edit your question, I see you using a for instead of a recursive function. Is that right? If you are using for (which is synchrone) which contains async functions, your functions will be called multiple times but only with the final value of your for.

Answer (score 0):

If you make foo like this

```
function foo (query1,query2,query3){ 
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig);
    function runQuery(query) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) reject(error);
                resolve(results);
            })
        })
    }

    return runQuery(query1).then(results => {
        return runQuery(query2);
    }).then(results => {
        return runQuery(query3);
    })
}
```